# using a variable outside a function in jquery

Tags: jquery

I am attempting to use a variable outside a function.

I have already defined the variable before the function, but am getting a NaN (the variable is a value) when I attempting to output it.

Below is my code, and here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8R7NW/).

```
$(function() {

    // inital values
    var total = $("#total").val("0");

    // slider A  
    $( "#pricea" ).slider({
      value:0,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function(event, ui) {                 
          $("#pricea").val(ui.value);                             
          var aaa = $("#pricea").val();  
          var bbb = $("#priceb").val();
          var total = $("#total").val(+aaa + +bbb);            
      }        
    });

    // slider B
    $( "#priceb" ).slider({
      value:0,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      step: 50,
      slide: function(event, ui) {                 
          $("#pricea").val(ui.value);                             
          var aaa = $("#pricea").val();  
          var bbb = $("#priceb").val();  
          var total = $("#total").val(+aaa + +bbb);
      }        
    });

   $("#totalplus").val(+total + 10);


  });
```

The variable is var `total`. I am attempting to output it with the element `#totalplus`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your total variable holds a jquery object, not the value itself, hence it is not a number.

You would have to use the total.val() value in the last line like this :

```
$("#totalplus").val(parseInt(total.val()) + 10);
```

And then you can add this same line at the end of your two slide events.

Also, as devnull69 mentioned, you don't have to redefine the total variable.

Here's an updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8R7NW/1/

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to understand that by using the `var` keyword you are redefining the variable `total` in the scope of the two slide functions as local variables. Setting the variable value there will not have any influence on the outer scope variable `total` outside of those functions.

If you omit the `var` keyword inside the functions, it should be possible to access the value outside of the functions.

BUT: Callback functions are of asynchronous nature, so your last line of code will most probably be executed before the value changes inside the callback.

Solution: Everything you want to do with the changed value of `total` must be done inside the callbacks (including outputting the value).